# How to retrieve image from parse.com

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Hi i am new to using parse.com
Actually iam trying to save image in parse.com and retriving it.. But i successfully saved image as a `PFFile`  [image]

in parse.com dashboard it showing like this

[image]

Now how can i retrive image and show in UIImageView

I tryied like this but its not working..

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
    [query whereKey:@"userName" containsString:@"ravi"];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"ID" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            PFFile *im = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
            _getImg.image = im;
        }}];
```

Here i want to retrive the particular image of `userName ravi`

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve the image, you need to:

1. Query for the `PFObject` in question
2. Use `-[PFFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:]` to retrieve the `PFFile`'s data
3. Create a `UIImage` with the resulting `NSData`

   ```
   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];

   [query whereKey:@"userName" containsString:@"ravi"];

   [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
       if (!object) {
           return NSLog(@"%@", error);
       }

       PFFile *imageFile = object[@"imageFile"];

       [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
           if (!data) {
               return NSLog(@"%@", error);
           }

           // Do something with the image
           self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
       }];
   }];
   ```

As an aside, unless purely for experimentation, or you're performing some operation off of the main thread, I would avoid saving the `PFObject` synchronously using `-[PFObject save]` and use instead, the asynchronous version, `-[PFObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use getObjectInBackgroundWithId: method in your case.
Instead you can use getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock: method to retrieve the first instance.